# Definition of the reduction map on isogenies

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

This is a follow-up to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352060/definition-of-the-natural-reduction-map-tilde-phi-for-phie-1-to-e-2-an), but I think sufficiently new to merit a new question.

The answer to that question implies that defining a canonical reduction map between the isogenies from $E_1 / L$ to $E_2 / L$ and the isogenies between their reductions at some prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L$ is "messy at best" without using the Neron model. I don't doubt that the Neron model is exceptionally useful here, but I'm wondering why we can't use the proposition stated earlier (II.2.2) that if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are defined over $L$ then there exists a finite extension $L'$ of $L$ such that every isogeny from $E_1$ to $E_2$ is defined over $L'$?

Instead of using the Neron model, can we just modify the hypotheses of Proposition II.4.4 to say: Let $E_1 / L$ and $E_2 / L$ be elliptic curves with good reduction at some $\mathfrak{p}$ of $L$. Let $L'$ be a finite extension of $L$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(E_1 , E_2)$ is defined over $L'$ and $E_1$, $E_2$ have good reduction at a prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $L'$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$.

We can then take the usual minimal Weierstrass models for $E_1, E_2$ over the completion of $L'$ at $\mathfrak{P}$, and scale all our isogenies so that their coefficients are in the ring of integers of $L'_{\mathfrak{P}}$ since our curves are projective varieites. Then it seems there is a "natural map" between $\operatorname{Hom}(E_1, E_2)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\tilde{E_1},\tilde{E_2})$ just by reduction of coefficients modulo $\mathfrak{P}$. Are there some subtleties in making this map that I'm missing?

Comment: Is the issue really that the isogeny might not be defined over $L$ (but then why would you hope to reduce it to the residue field of $L$)? I’m thinking of a different problem: how do you know that your isogeny has integer coefficients in the minimal Weierstrass models?

Comment: This is what I was trying to fix by scaling in the last paragraph. If you think of the isogeny as a projective map then you can scale all the coefficients by a constant without changing the map, so just scale the coefficients by the largest power of a uniformizer appearing in any of the denominators... you still need to check that the reduction defined this way is an isogeny of course, but that seems plausible...

Comment: The fact that this approach works is basically the Neron model property. Proving that the reduction map is injective and preserves degrees also looks somewhat unpleasant (you’re forced to reason with points over a field extension and their reductions, etc)…