# Reducing elliptic curves -- why can we also reduce the endomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, projective-varieties

Let $K$ be a local field with residue field $k$, let $E/K$ an elliptic curve of good reduction, $\tilde{E}/k$. The reduction map $E(K)\to \tilde{E}(k)$ respects addition, which leads to a natural injection $\operatorname{End}(E)\to\operatorname{End}(\tilde{E})$ whenever $\operatorname{End}(E)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

But apparently, we always have an injection $\operatorname{End}(E)\to \operatorname{End}(\tilde{E})$, even when $E$ has complex multiplication. Lang, in his book on elliptic functions, says this follows from 'general reduction theory'.

**Question:** How does one go about constructing this injection, or even proving it exists?

I tried reducing the coefficients of the homogeneous polynomials, but that doesn't work, at least not for varieties in general. For example, consider the morphism $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q}_2)\to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q}_2)$ given by $(2X:Y)$. For reference, I'm using Silverman's definition of (projective) varieties, from his book on elliptic curves.

**EDIT:** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352060/definition-of-the-natural-reduction-map-tilde-phi-for-phie-1-to-e-2-an?rq=1) is a near duplicate. However, I am interested in an explicit construction of the reductions of endomorphisms.

Comment: Before posting this question, I searched online for quite a bit and found nothing. But now that I've posted it, Stack-Exchange shows me a 'related question': https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352060/definition-of-the-natural-reduction-map-tilde-phi-for-phie-1-to-e-2-an?rq=1 which my question seems to be a duplicate of...

Comment: The short answer: projective means you can clear denominators in the coefficients (of the polynomials defining the morphism), then reduce mod $p$.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey So how would that work for the example in my question? $(2X:Y)$ has no denominators, yet if we naively reduce modulo $2$, the image of $(1:0)\in\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is not defined.

Comment: indeed. Unless you cleared too many denominators (and ended up with a map nowhere defined) you have a rational map between smooth projective curves over the residue field, just extend this map to any points where it's not defined (in this case it makes it constant). That's why you need the good reduction assumption.